# iOS sends the notification object to UserNotificationCenter and to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, usernotifications

When the app is closed and the user taps on a notification:

1) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called with a remoteNotification object. I set the rootViewController here as expected

2) userNotificationCenter(_, didReceive, withCompletionHandler) is also called.

The thing is, I don't want to do anything on step 2 because I already handled the notification on step 1). But, if the app was in the foreground or background, I do want to handle the notification in step 2). I don't know how to differentiate these two cases.

Comment: What about trying to set the rootViewController in the userNotificationCenter function instead of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? This way it is called only once, because, the userNotificationCenter is a Delegate function which is called when a user taps on a notification.

Comment: Because I do need to set a rootViewController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, otherwise the app crashes

Comment: Mhmmm, you could add a variable which sets if the user went to the background state or if the app is being just opened. So when the user goes to background, lets set wasInBackground = true, so if wasInBackground is true you handle the notification, if not, then don't.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you **verify** that they are both being called upon taping on notification or it's just that you thought that's what's going to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* they are for separate concerns.

That is `userNotificationCenter(_, didReceive, withCompletionHandler)` is for handling Responses. What action did the user click, did they just swipe to clear it? Did they respond to the message right there?

But the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is there only for receiving a callback, it's just there to tell you that the app was launched through the notification after it was killed/suspended...be aware...and here's your chance to do launch/do whatever you usually do during app launches

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `flag` variable in `AppDelegate` class.
The **initial value is false**, with the name `isAppActive`.
This variable will **set to true whenever** `func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)` is called.

So, you can check if app already finished the first setup/initialization or not. AppDelegate instance is a shared instance so you can check it anywhere at runtime.

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` is called only once when app is completely loaded into RAM. After that, you can check `isAppActive` value. Ex:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    if isAppActive {
        // Do your logic here
    }
```